# calling .val() on date_select element returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to obtain the selected date from a date_select:

```
    <%= form_for(@newevent) do |f| %>

        <%= f.date_select :day, { id: "date-select"} %>

        <button id="check-button" type="button">Check</button>

<% end %>
```

using JQuery/Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', "#check-button", function(){

var selectedDate = $("#date-select").val();

alert(selectedDate);

var checkList = []; //creates array to store customer ids
$("#check-list li input").each(function(){ //for each listed colleague...
    if( $(this).is(":checked")){ //if check-box is ticked
        checkList.push($(this).val()); //add id to list
    }
});

$.ajax({
        url: '/events/check',
        data: {checkList: checkList , selected_date: selectedDate },
        method: "POST"
    }
);
```

});

for reference here is where `:day` is defined in my migration file:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|

      t.timestamps
      t.references :calendar, foreign_key: true
      ...

      t.date :day

      ...

    end
```

However, on alert the returned value is "undefined". Why is this happening? I would like it to return the a value in the form `YYYY-MM-DD`. Apologies if this is obvious, but I am new to programming and can't seem to fix this one myself

Comment: probably because element doesn't exist when you run that code. Please show full context. That snippet alone is not enough to troubleshoot from

Comment: @charlietfl ok I will edit my question

Comment: That code makes it look like you could have multiple dom elements with the same "date-select" id.

Comment: @Luke3butler I don't understand what you mean

Comment: This code is going to create an element for each @newevent and all of these elements will have 'date-select' as the ID:  `<%= form_for(@newevent) do |f| %><%= f.date_select :day, { id: "date-select"} %>`

Comment: @Luke3butler I thought by doing that, it gave the id "date-select" to the html element?

Comment: @SCraig it does, but if there is more than one @newevent, then there will be multiple html elements with that ID. In chrome developer tools console enter in `$("#date-select")` and see what happens. it could be that all you need is `$("#date-select")[0].val()`

Answer (score 0):

Date_select, according to the rails api "Returns a set of select tags (one for year, month, and day)".  Your javascript is going to have to deal with three separate selects and construct a date from them.  Look at your generated HTML to get the id's.

Comment: ok, do you know any useful methods in JS/JQuery that would aid this?

Comment: @SCraig There's not JS/JQuery methods for this. Use Chrome/Firefox developer tools to explore the source, and use the console to see what `$("#date-select")` actually contains.